# How to save cropped images with their original filename?

Tags: python, save, filenames

i wrote a small code block to save croppped images , in files based on their classes .
The thing is , those images are saved with a prefix BB_Shirt or BB_Short with respect to their classes , but now i want to save them with the same prefix but adding also the original filename of the image ex :

I have these image : Prv_image_1021

And the cropped objects would be saved as the following :
(suppose there is 4 objects) , i want my output to be 
BB_Shirt_1021_1 , 
BB_Short_1021_2 , 
BB_Shirt_1021_3 , 
BB_Short_1021_4

Here's my code :

```
for i in idxs.flatten():
    # extract the bounding box coordinates
    (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
    (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])

    # draw a bounding box rectangle and label on the image
    color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
    text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
    cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.5, color, 2)
    # Saving our detected objects with respect to the Label
    img=image[y:y + h,x:x + w]
    if LABELS[classIDs[i]] == 'short':
        filename = "Shorts/BB_short_%d.jpg"%i
        cv2.imwrite(filename,img)
    else:
        filename = "Shirts/BB_shirt_%d.jpg"%i
        cv2.imwrite(filename,img)
    i+=1
```

Any Suggestion on how to do that would be much appreciated , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of index using enumerate() and then append the index to the file name.

```
list_idxs = idxs.flatten()
for index, i in enumerate(list_idxs):
    # extract the bounding box coordinates
    (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
    (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])

    # draw a bounding box rectangle and label on the image
    color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
    text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
    cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.5, color, 2)
    # Saving our detected objects with respect to the Label
    img=image[y:y + h,x:x + w]
    if LABELS[classIDs[i]] == 'short':
        filename = f"Shorts/BB_short_{i}_{index}.jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(filename,img)
    else:
        filename = f"Shirts/BB_shirt_{i}_{index}.jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(filename,img)
    i+=1
```